# command to enter idle state

Tags: wayland

I am on Ubuntu 22.04 and you know if you are  away from the keyboard for 10 minutes the apps go idle is there a command that make it in idle state faster ? not suspend just idle.

Comment: Do you mean "screen lock" (requires login password to unlock)?  Nothing "goes idle", the lock screen just displays in front of everything.

Comment: when I lock the screen, it does not put the apps like teams into idle state immediately